# When (if ever) are we getting our own domain name?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Right now we're currently puzzling.stackexchange.com but will we ever be "puzzling.com" or something similar like https://stackoverflow.com/ or https://superuser.com/

When is it actually available for us, and what should we (if we do, there's nothing wrong with out current domain name) change it to?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a more specific domain is only available when the site makes it out of beta. I think there are other discussions on our name when we get out of Beta.

Comment: @mdc32 Once upon a time, sites got a custom domain when they graduated, but that hasn't been the case for a few years now.

Comment: SE Sites don't get a custom domain anymore, just like Kevin said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Trilogy (S[OFU]) and a few exceptions are the only sites to have custom domain names.

(The exceptions are [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) because it's a "branch" of sorts, [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) because it's not a normal Q&A site, [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) because of its relationship to Ubuntu, and [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net) for historical reasons.)

Comment: There are a couple others ([Seasoned Advice](http://seasonedadvice.com), [Arqade](http://arqade.com), maybe more; they all redirect to their SE domains now).  At one time all sites were given a domain with their design upon graduation, but they quickly decided that wasn't sustainable and stopped it a few years ago.